# How can I find which modules alter my form?

Tags: 7, forms

Is there a way to debug the list of modules which alters my form (using form_ID).

I can get a list of modules implementing `hook_form_alter` using `module_implements('form_alter')` but how can I know which form they are altering?

I need a function which takes my `form_id` as input and returns the *list of modules* which alters it.

I want to create a drupal page in which a textbox gets input from developers and returns that modules which alters it.

Comment: Do you need function, or you just want to check who is altering your form?

Comment: I need a function for it. Is there anything already exists or else how can I build it?

Comment: I think that it's not possible to have function which can guarantee that it can find all hooks, which altering your form. Why do you need it?

Comment: You can find all the form_alter functions as you said and then run them one by one and diff variables after each call. Even then, an alter function might have complex logic to decide when to alter your form.

Comment: why you don't just search for the form_id in all source project folder using an IDE

Comment: I want to create a drupal page in which a textbox gets input from developers and returns that modules which alters it.

Comment: No such function exists; I'd be surprised if it wasn't quite a big job to achieve what you're asking, given the complex nature of both the form and hook systems. You'll almost certainly need to patch a few core methods

Comment: this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3978344/3653989